# Elements resize in other browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, web, compatibility

I'm working on a website www.50s.co and it looks fine in chrome but then i look in firefox or IE and the background pictures are sized differently, at least it looks like they are but it's saying the image size is the same so some element(s) on the page are causing a problem but I can't see anything wrong.

I just want the website to look as it does on chrome in other browsers.

What is causing the image to overlap the blue border at the bottom of the page and how do i fix it? (The Join Us page is the main problem, but the others do it a little bit)

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/450fav.jpg"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="discount, ariels, air conditioning, airport transfers, auto electricians, bathrooms, beauty salons, bedrooms, blinds, curtains, boilers, brake, clutch, builders, burglar alarms, car body repairs, car hire, carpenters, carpet cleaning, carpet fitting, central heating, chiropodists, chiropractors, cleaning services, domestic appliance repair, double glazing, drains, electricians, estate agents, exausts, fencing, garage doors, garages, garage services, gas, guttering, kitchens, landscaper, gardening, grass cutting, locksmith, locksmiths, mot, mots, painters, decoraters, paving, contractors, pest control, plasterers, plumbers, removal, romavals, storage, roofing, roofer, skip hire, tree surgeon, tree services, tyres, vets, wills, probate writting">
<link href="browsers.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="ga.js"></script><script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
        <script src="jquery.min.js"> </script><style type="text/css"></style>

        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui-1.10.4.slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link href="jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link href="jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link href="jquery.ui.slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                /*$(".scroll").click(function(event){       
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},900);
                });*/

                $('#change_city').change(function(){
                    $.post( "ajax.php", { city_id: $(this).val() }, function( data ) {
                      $( "#change_postcode" ).html( data );
                    });
                });

                $( "#menu_toggle" ).click(function() {
                  $( "#top_menu" ).toggle();
                });
            });
         </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Join 450s</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="border1"> </div>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" id="menu_toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="http://50s.co"><br><img src="/images/450slogo.png"></a><br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
                  <div class="container-fluid">


                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top_menu">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a class="active" href="http://www.50s.co" data-hover="Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.50s.co/why.php" data-hover="Why Us?">Why Us?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.50s.co/offers.php" data-hover="Offers">Offers</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#E31818" href="http://www.50s.co/advertise.php" data-hover="Advertise">Join Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.50s.co/contact.php" data-hover="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Slider1"></div>
    </div>


<div class='border2'> </div>
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;"><img class="advertise1" style="position:absolute;width:100%;border-radius:0px;" src="images/advertise1.png"/></div>
<div><img class="advertise2" style="position:absolute;width:100%;border-radius:0px;" src="images/advertise2.png"/></div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 box1">     
                  <div class="box-wrap">

<h1 class="title1" style="font-family:'arial';text-align:center;margin-top:2%;">Join 450s</h1>

<h4 class="heading1" style="font-family:'arial';padding:0px;text-align:center;"><p>Reasons to offer a discount to people over 50:</p></h4>
<h4><ul type="circle">
<li>64.1 million people live in the United Kingdom.</li><br>
<li>43% or 21.6 million people in the UK are over 50 years old.</li><br>
<li>14,226 people turn 50 every week.</li><br>
<li>People over 50 control 80% of private wealth.</li><br>
<li>The 50 plus generation is the fastest growing group of internet users.</li><br>
<li>The number of 50 plus people using the internet has increased by 80% since 2002.</li><br>
<li>Not all people over 50 are wealthy.</li><br>
<li>Pensioners genuinely need such discounts from private businesses.</li><br>

<li>All online lead service providers are fee based, at an average of 35+ Pounds per lead,
which they sell 3 times over and put you in a price war with your competition.</li><br>

<li>We offer exclusive leads, all over 50 year olds</li><br>
<li>No price war, No Monthly fees</li><br>
<li>No Cost per Refferal, Direct contact with the client</li><br>
<li>No third party referrals, Payment options </li><br>
</ul></h4>
<h3 class="heading2" style="font-family:'arial';padding:5px;text-align:center;">Call Today for the Best Exclusive Leads in your area!</h3>

<strong><h2 class="heading1" style="font-family:'arial';text-align:center;">Call Now On: 0207 078 4229</h2></strong><br>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style='margin-top:3%;' class='border2'> </div>

        <img style="
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
    position:relative; clear:bottom;
display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" src="images/standards.jpg" />        



</body>
</html>
```

> `Blockquote`

Comment: post the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have absolutely positioned images in there as "background" images (but in img tags!). This really doesn't make sense - absolutely positioned elements don't adjust their size automatically.
define the images as real background images of the elements which they should span: `background: url(…) …`with the size, attachment and repeat settings you need.

Comment: Thanks, it did cross my mind to make it a background, probably should of just tried it.